# text on top of image from bootstrap nav-pills

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using nav-pills from bootstrap 3 to display my image banner on the corresponding tab. I want to have an unordered list on the "#contact-us" (Corporate, americas/caribbean, africa/middle east, europe, asia/australia) on top of the banner image and have both the text and image to be responsive. I can get the list on top of the image, but once I shrink the browser the list would run out of the banner image.

What do I need to do in my css so that my text would stay within the banner even when i am shrinking the image?

Below is my html. 
Thanks in advance!

```
 <div class="banner-tabs">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills tab-titles" id="pills-first">
        <li><a href="#about-us" data-toggle="pill">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#careers" data-toggle="pill">Careers</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#contact-us" data-toggle="pill">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul> <!-- nav nav-pills -->  
    </div> <!-- container -->

    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="about-us">
        <img src="../images/delete-1.png" class="tab-banner" />
      </div> <!-- about us -->

      <div class="tab-pane" id="careers">
        <img src="../images/delete-2.png" class="tab-banner" />
      </div> <!-- careers -->

      <div class="tab-pane active" id="contact-us">
        <img src="../images/delete-1.png" class="tab-banner">
          <div class="continents">
            <p>Click to view:</p>
            <ul>
              <li id="corporate"><a>Corporate</a></li>
              <li id="americas-caribbean"><a>Americas/Caribbean</a></li>
              <li id="africa-middle-east"><a>Africa/Middle East</a></li>
              <li id="europe"><a>Europe</a></li>
              <li id="asia-australia"><a>Asia/Australia</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div> <!-- continents -->
     </div>
   </div> <!-- row -->
 </div> <!-- corporate-content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can provide something like a codepen example ? 
Use this as a base : http://codepen.io/alogonzac/pen/vOKELp

```
<div class="banner-tabs">...</div>
```